# Ignite large query stores data in memory even when onHeapCacheEnabled is set to false

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, ignite, in-memory-database

I am running ignite 2.3 in embedded mode which means my default mode of data storage is off-heap. I have not enabled on heap cache.

The problem is when I run a large query, the data is stored ON the heap for a long time before it finally garbage collects. Is this expected? Why does it take so long for JVM to garbage collect this data.

I am concerned because as a result of my query, and the data it occupies on heap this will affect my application performance.

My CacheConfiguration are as follows:

- data region max size: 12288000000L
- CacheMode.LOCAL
- indexedType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite always stores data off-heap, on-heap caching is a feature that gives you ability to use Java heap as a cache for off-heap memory and configure eviction policies specific to this cache.

So, the data that you observe on Java heap with onHeapCacheEnabled=false is not Ignite cache data in your case, but a Java application memory footprint which is absolutely expected to exist. If you are experiencing application peformance issues that are connected with GC, check [Preparing for Production](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.4/docs/preparing-for-production) and namely [Garbage Collection Tuning](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.4/docs/jvm-and-system-tuning) sections of Ignite documentation for tuning tips or ask any specific questions here.

Regards.

Comment: okay. Makes sense. Stupid Question: I have checked all of the ignite APIs but there is no method like SqlCallBackHandler which would fetch a bunch of records and pass it to processing and continue this process so that my heap size does not increase manifolds but when I explicitly tell it to GC the memory drops back to negligible.

Comment: SqlFieldsQuery has lazy flag, it minimizes heap consumption in price of performance: `SqlFieldsQuery.setLazy(true)`

Comment: I tried the same. It did not have any impact on the heap size. (For testing purposes) What my code does is gets a large data set, and just iterated over it without even assigning the data to a variable i.e if iterator.hasNext(). ->  iterator.next(). What am I missing here? BTW I am using QueryCursor.

Comment: Looks like ignite is retrieving all data even though I am using an iterator and iterating over it. That is not what I want, I want to implement pagination of sorts with ignite.